# Building dChart based on Container in Vaadin

Tags: java, widget, vaadin, vaadin7

I have got a table builded based on `SQLContainer`. I want to build a chart also based on `SQLContainer`. It would be easy with `VaadinChart` add-on however I don't want to pay for it, I'm looking for something free. So I have installed `dChart` widget building chart based on container like this:

```
void refreshPieDChart(Container container){
    Collection<?> itemIDS= container.getItemIds();
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //1
    for (Object itemID : itemIDS)
    {
         Property property= container.getContainerProperty(itemID, "status");
         String status = (String)property.getValue();

         if (countMap.containsKey(status)) {
             countMap.put(status, countMap.get(status) + 1);
         } else {
             countMap.put(status, 1);
         }
    }

    DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries();

    if (countMap == null || countMap.size() < 1) {
        dataSeries.newSeries().add("No records", 1);
    }else{
        for (String key : countMap.keySet()) {
            String legendRow = key + "\t" + countMap.get(key).toString();
            dataSeries.newSeries().add(legendRow, countMap.get(key));
        }
    }
    chart.setDataSeries(dataSeries).show();
}
```

However it takes too long, for example: first for marked with `//1`

```
300 - 1400 records : 500 - 1800 ms
```

It means that user need to wait 2 seconds till page will be repainted...

Is there any faster way, than I have implemented, to build `dChart` from `Container`? Or maybe there are other free chart widgets that implement this already?

**EDIT:**

I made some more tests and all calls of `getContainerProperty(id,prop)` take 5/6 of time processing :/ Any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at an answer here:
[Multithreading refresh UI in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423764/multithreading-refresh-ui-in-vaadin)

I was able to work around counting thousands of `status`es.