# Multithreading refresh UI in Vaadin

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, vaadin

I'm trying to implement a multithreading refresh UI in my Vaadin app.

Part of this UI is a `dChart` based on container. To build `dChart` Im iterating through container and count elements by one of their properties, like this:

```
        Collection<?> itemIDS = container.getItemIds();

        for (Object itemID : itemIDS) {
            Property property = container.getContainerProperty(itemID, "status");
            String status = (String) property.getValue();
            if (countMap.containsKey(status)) {
                countMap.put(status, countMap.get(status) + 1);
            } else {
                countMap.put(status, 1);
            }
        }
```

However it takes over 2-3 seconds if container has thousands of elements.

User just can't wait so long to refresh an UI.

I read that i can build my UI and later just refresh it using `@Push` Vaadin annotation, after dChart is fully built.

So i build something like this:

```
{
//class with @Push
  void refreshPieDChart(GeneratedPropertyContainer container) {
    new InitializerThread(ui, container).start();
  }

  class InitializerThread extends Thread {
    private LogsUI parentUI;
    private GeneratedPropertyContainer container;

    InitializerThread(LogsUI ui, GeneratedPropertyContainer container) {
        parentUI = ui;
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //building dChart etc etc... which takes over 2-3 seconds

        // Init done, update the UI after doing locking
        parentUI.access(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chart.setDataSeries(dataSeries).show();
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

However if i refresh page few times, it is generating errors about `SQLContainer`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A trasaction is already active!
```

Becouse after few refreshes, my multiple threads are running parallel using the same SQLContainer.

To fix that, I want to stop all working refresh threads except last one to eliminate concurrent problem. How i can do it? Maybe other solution?

**EDIT:**
I have tried smth like this, but problem still remains, is it a correct way to prevent concurrent problem?

```
{
  private static final Object mutex = new Object();
//class with @Push
  void refreshPieDChart(GeneratedPropertyContainer container) {
    new InitializerThread(ui, container).start();
  }

  class InitializerThread extends Thread {
    private LogsUI parentUI;
    private GeneratedPropertyContainer container;

    InitializerThread(LogsUI ui, GeneratedPropertyContainer container) {
        parentUI = ui;
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //is it correct way to prevent concurrent problem? 
        synchronized(mutex){
            //method to refresh/build chart which takes 2-3s.
        }
        // Init done, update the UI after doing locking
        parentUI.access(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chart.setDataSeries(dataSeries).show();
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider lazy loading for your thousands of entries?

Comment: @tk12 this is exacly what im doing right now, or not? Im building UI (Chart too) only on user request (refresh, enter my webapp). But when i want to build a chart i need to get ALL my data in one moment (otherwise my chart will be out-of-date)

Comment: Do all of the data get displayed on the screen at once? That's what I meant by lazy loading. If the user only sees a part of the data at once, you can lazy load the data as it gets displayed on the screen, hence increasing loading performance. But if you want to _use_ **all** the data at once, then what I'm suggesting might not suit your needs.

Comment: @tk12 If my chart is counting elements in SQLContainer, you just can't use lazy loading becouse of you need to count every single element, that means you need to load it anyway. You are right that lazy loading suits perfectly for loading part of data, e.g: scrolling table. But in this particular case i need to get all data.

Comment: @ilovkatie I think you should do the counting in SQL, then it should be fast enough. Then you don't multithreading.

Comment: @HenriKerola I was thinking about that, however there are mulitple options in my UI that are changing my SQLContainer filters. That means i need to prepare SQL for every possible filters combination... Thats a lot of SQL statements in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did:

[Henri Kerola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270910/henri-kerola) points me pretty obvious idea: do counting in SQL. As i said I was thinking about that but that would means I need to prepare SQL for every possible filters combination. That is a pretty complicated and doesn't look good.

But this realised me that if I'm using SQLContainer with filters for my table, I can do the same for counting. I just need to create second `SQLContainer` with my own`FreeformQuery` and `FreeformStatementDelegate`.

If i will create all of above, i can just add THE SAME filters to both containers however i dont need to count elements now becouse 2nd container holds values for me. It sounds complecated but take a look on my code:

```
FreeformQuery myQuery = new MyFreeformQuery(pool);
FreeformQuery countQuery = new CountMyFreeformQuery(pool);

SQLContainer myContainer = new SQLContainer(myQuery);  //here i hold my all records as in a Question
SQLContainer countContainer = new SQLContainer(countQuery);  //here i hold computed count(*) and status
```

**MyFreeformQuery.java** looks like:

```
class ProcessFreeformQuery extends FreeformQuery {

private static final String QUERY_STRING = "SELECT request_date, status, id_foo FROM foo";
private static final String COUNT_STRING = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo";
private static final String PK_COLUMN_NAME = "id_foo";

MyFreeformQuery(JDBCConnectionPool connectionPool) {
    super(QUERY_STRING, connectionPool, PK_COLUMN_NAME);
    setDelegate(new AbstractFreeformStatementDelegate() {

        protected String getPkColumnName() {
            return PK_COLUMN_NAME;
        }

        protected String getQueryString() {
            return QUERY_STRING;
        }

        protected String getCountString() {
            return COUNT_STRING;
        }
    });
}
```

and most important **CountFreeformQuery.java** looks like:

```
public class CountFreeformQuery extends FreeformQuery {

private static final String QUERY_STRING_GROUP = "SELECT status, count(*) as num FROM foo GROUP BY status";
private static final String QUERY_STRING = "SELECT status, count(*) as num FROM foo";
private static final String GROUP_BY = "foo.status";

public CountFreeformQuery(JDBCConnectionPool connectionPool) {
    super(QUERY_STRING_GROUP, connectionPool);
    setDelegate(new CountAbstractFreeformStatementDelegate() {
        protected String getQueryString() {
            return QUERY_STRING;
        }

        protected String getGroupBy(){
            return GROUP_BY;
        }

    });
}
}
```

Now if i want to refresh `dChart` after smth like that:

```
myContainer.addContainerFilter(new Between(DATE_PROPERTY, getTimestamp(currentDate), getOneDayAfter(currentDate)));
```

I just do the same with `countContainer`:

```
countContainer.addContainerFilter(new Between(DATE_PROPERTY, getTimestamp(currentDate), getOneDayAfter(currentDate)));
```

And pass it to method which dont need to count elements, just add all container to map and then to dChart like that:

```
    Map<String, Long> countMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    Collection<?> itemIDS = container.getItemIds();
    for (Object itemID : itemIDS) {
        Property statusProperty = container.getContainerProperty(itemID, "status");
        Property numProperty = container.getContainerProperty(itemID, "num");
        countMap.put((String) statusProperty.getValue(), (Long) numProperty.getValue());
    }
```

Now i have `status`es of elements in `myContainer` counted, no need to multithreading or writing tons of sql.

Thanks guys for suggestions.